# How to download map programmatically in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit, offline

Working on Mapkit frame work.

I Would like to download certain area of the map by programmatically.

And also would like to show that downloaded map in offline.How can i do that.

Can any one help me will highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short Not passible with MapKit.

I have used a third party SDK for the same. Please review the link below

https://www.mapbox.com/developers/

**Objective C**

```
@import Mapbox;

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    MGLMapView *mapView = [[MGLMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];

    mapView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    // set the map's center coordinates and zoom level
    [mapView setCenterCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(40.7326808, -73.9843407)
                       zoomLevel:12
                        animated:NO];

    [self.view addSubview:mapView];
}

@end
```

**Swift**

```
import Mapbox

class ViewController: UIViewController, MGLMapViewDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let mapView = MGLMapView(frame: view.bounds)
        mapView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]

        // set the map's center coordinate
        mapView.setCenterCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.7326808,
                                                           longitude: -73.9843407),
                                    zoomLevel: 12, animated: false)
        view.addSubview(mapView)
    }
}
```

For detailed documentation please refer : https://www.mapbox.com/help/first-steps-ios-sdk/

Please take a note that it is not free : https://www.mapbox.com/pricing/

Comment: Thank for your reply. i will check it.

Comment: Here is the demo https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/tree/master/platform/ios